# Alternative resources for landscape and portrait orientation

Tags: orientation, drawable, landscape, portrait

I have two activities and the layout of these activities have background images that are different for portrait and landscape . i have make different folders named drawable-land-hdpi and drawabe-port-hdpi and put the images in these. But when i start application it loads the right image according to orientation of device , but after that when i am changing the orientation , it is not loading the image from portrait when i change orientation to portrait  and also is not loading image from landscape when i change orientation to landscape.

Does any on e know the reason ? Please help .
Any kind of help and suggestions will be appreciated.
Thanks, 
Munazza